# Js app runs locally but Heroku Throws and error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I built an app that runs well on locally. But when I deploy on heroku it crashes and shows me this.

```
Error: Cannot find module './dist'
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130104+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130104+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/optional-require/index.js
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130120+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/index.js
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130120+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/index.js
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130121+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/binary.js
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130121+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130121+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130121+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/node_modules/mongoose/index.js
2023-01-06T22:40:19.130122+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/index.js
```

My code is in this repo: https://github.com/Franttisekpetruv/Carelooker
Website is:https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/calm-crag-33682

I understand that some modules. I re-install npm and it did nothing...
I am expecting my app to run, connect to atlas etc... since it runs locally I even paid $5 to heroku, was that also necessary?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a folder named `dist`?

Comment: From what I knnow, I don't make the dist folder and i could not find anything online.

Comment: I don't use Heroku, but you should look into the docs about the build folder. Heroku is looking for a directory to serve your file, and I assume that if you don't supply one `dist` is default.